# apt-get update command in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt

We have installed Ubuntu server 12.04. We upgraded it with the command `apt-get upgrade` but when it comes to `apt-get update`, it stuck and cannot find the exact header. Secondly `virtinst` command does not run. How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Usually waiting for headers means that you are not able to connect to the server. Are you behind a proxy? Are you sure you are able to connect to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem somewhat similar to this, dont remember exactly but I managed to do the updating and upgrading to raring ringtail with the software updater. You could try that route and see if it works.

cheers !